# How do I combine "I speak Japanese" with "I like to ..."?

Tags: grammar, particles, nominalization

So to say you like something, you you could say:

```
僕は[blank]がすきです。
```

and to say something like "I speak Japanese", you could say:

```
僕は日本語が話します。
```

So say I wanted to say I like to speak Japanese, how could I combine the two sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nominalize the verb phrase, because 好き is an adjective and can only modify a noun. The way you do that in Japanese is to add a nominalizer (in this case, の）to the verb phrase:

> 日本語を話す = I speak Japanese
>
> 日本語を話す**の** = the act of speaking Japanese

Now you can put them together and say:

> 僕は日本語を話すのが好きです。

Literally: "As for me, the act of speaking Japanese is liked." Note that you can only nominalize a verb when it's in a short form, not ます form:

> **X** 僕は日本語を話しますのが好きです。**ungrammatical**